# Remove itens from JSON string based on a comparison between two JSON strings - C#

Tags: c#, json, linq

Given 2 JSON strings:

```
[
   {
      "id":"BA",
      "description":"BrandA",
      "values":[
         {
            "id":"CategoryA",
            "description":"CategoryA"
         },
         {
            "id":"CategoryB",
            "description":"CategoryB"
         },
         {
            "id":"CategoryC",
            "description":"CategoryC"
         },
         {
            "id":"CategoryD",
            "description":"CategoryD"
         },
         {
            "id":"CategoryE",
            "description":"CategoryE"
         },
         {
            "id":"CategoryF",
            "description":"CategoryF"
         },
         {
            "id":"CategoryG",
            "description":"CategoryG"
         },
         {
            "id":"CategoryH",
            "description":"CategoryH"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"BB",
      "description":"BrandB",
      "values":[
         {
            "id":"CategoryA",
            "description":"CategoryA"
         },
         {
            "id":"CategoryB",
            "description":"CategoryB"
         },
         {
            "id":"CategoryC",
            "description":"CategoryC"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

AND

```
[
   {
      "id":"BA",
      "description":"BrandA",
      "values":[
         {
            "id":"CategoryA",
            "description":"CategoryA"
         },
         {
            "id":"CategoryC",
            "description":"CategoryC"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"BB",
      "description":"BrandB",
      "values":[
         {
            "id":"CategoryB",
            "description":"CategoryB"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

First one is the original. The second are the values that I want to remove from the original. So basically, if there is a match on brand and category between first and second JSON, regardless of the order of the elements, I want that match to be removed.

The expected result would be someting like this:

```
[
   {
      "id":"BA",
      "description":"BrandA",
      "values":[
         {
            "id":"CategoryB",
            "description":"CategoryB"
         },
         {
            "id":"CategoryD",
            "description":"CategoryD"
         },
         {
            "id":"CategoryE",
            "description":"CategoryE"
         },
         {
            "id":"CategoryF",
            "description":"CategoryF"
         },
         {
            "id":"CategoryG",
            "description":"CategoryG"
         },
         {
            "id":"CategoryH",
            "description":"CategoryH"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"BB",
      "description":"BrandB",
      "values":[
         {
            "id":"CategoryA",
            "description":"CategoryA"
         },
         {
            "id":"CategoryC",
            "description":"CategoryC"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Catagory A and C in Brand A were removed as well as Category B in Brand B.

Based in some research, I was using https://github.com/wbish/jsondiffpatch.net, tried to work with it's functions, but so far I didn't manage to achieve the result I want. Also, to solve this by processing JSON direcly is not a must. If there is a simpler solution to achieve that by converting them to lists and use something like LINQ for example, it works for me as well (tried that, but didn't manage to find a way to do this comparison).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If performance does not matter, the JsonSerializer and LINQ can be used:

**Model**

```cs
public class JsonModel
{
    public class ValueModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ValueModel> Values { get; set; }
}
```

**Deserialize and LINQ**

```cs
string json1Str = @"[...]";

string json2Str = @"[...]";


var opt = new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
var json1 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<JsonModel>>(json1Str, opt);
var json2 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<JsonModel>>(json2Str, opt);

var result = json1.
    Join(json2, j1 => j1.Id, j2 => j2.Id, (j1, j2) => new JsonModel
    {
        Id = j1.Id,
        Description = j1.Description,
        Values = j1.Values.Where(j1 => !j2.Values.Select(val => val.Id).Contains(j1.Id))
    });
Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(result, new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true }));
}
```

**Result**

```js
[
  {
    "Id": "BA",
    "Description": "BrandA",
    "Values": [
      {
        "Id": "CategoryB",
        "Description": "CategoryB"
      },
      {
        "Id": "CategoryD",
        "Description": "CategoryD"
      },
      {
        "Id": "CategoryE",
        "Description": "CategoryE"
      },
      {
        "Id": "CategoryF",
        "Description": "CategoryF"
      },
      {
        "Id": "CategoryG",
        "Description": "CategoryG"
      },
      {
        "Id": "CategoryH",
        "Description": "CategoryH"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "BB",
    "Description": "BrandB",
    "Values": [
      {
        "Id": "CategoryA",
        "Description": "CategoryA"
      },
      {
        "Id": "CategoryC",
        "Description": "CategoryC"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```